# Syms command does not work in my Matlab 2008b

Tags: matlab, math, symbols, symbolic-math

My Matlab is 2008b version

when I give the following command :

```
x=syms('x')
```

it return the follwing message :

```
??? Undefined function or method 'syms' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

and the same for the command of the form :

```
 syms c1 c2 x
```

how to run the symbol math in Matlab 2008b ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you do not have the appropriate toolbox installed.

Run the command `ver` on the command line, and check whether the Symbolic Toolbox is one of the installed toolboxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can go in your Matlab installation path and click to uninstall the program. When it asks you to select, select `modify` and then in the installation page, you can select any toolbox you have not installed yet to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just :

`syms x;`

like this:

```
clc
clear
syms x;
f=(sin(x)^2)+log(x)+sqrt(x-1);
disp(subs(f,x,5));`
```